# Modify Login Error Messages in Magento 2.3 for Incorrect Password

Tags: magento2.3, password, global-messages

I'm looking to change the "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later." message that appears when someone types an incorrect password.

I see the text in .xml files in vendor/magento/module_customer, but I don't think these are the files I should rewrite. What file should I overwrite with a new module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CSV file at

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

and change the message as per you want.

```
"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.","Your custom message."
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: That did not work. Is there a sample CSV file that I can see anywhere else in the system?

Comment: after you change run all commands

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link to create a new theme: [Create a new storefront theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#theme-gen-walkthrough)

If frontend theme is already exists then create/update file on the following path:

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Just add following data and replace text "Your text message" as per your requirement:

```
"The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.","Your text message"
```

Run the deploy command to get localization changes and flush cache:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```